# Synonymise [unity-editor] and [unity3d-editor]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I wanted to propose a tag-sinonym for [unity3d-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-editor) namely [unity-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-editor) but I get

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

Both tags are quite new (about 80 questions each) but they actually seem to refer to the exact same thing only the `3` apparently causes the trouble.

---

It gets even more confusing since there is already the tag [[unity3d]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/info) for **general** questions about Unity3d and most questions I have reviewed  so far tagged `unity-editor` are actually more about the Unity3d [custom inspector scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) **not** as the tag description (which is very vague and in my opinion misleading) claims about Unity3d in general.

So some people actually ended up tagging their questions [unity-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-editor) instead [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) though that tag seems to be mostly used rather for editor-scripting specific questions (what the `unity3d-editor` tag is for).

(Also the description of `unity3d-editor` is not that good yet but I might work on this)

Comment: Agreed they should be synonyms. imo the tags containing "editor" should be about *the* editor or editor scripts, and not about Unity in general as a software. As the [tag:unity3d] exists for that.